# Setting dynamically an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

It seems complicated for me.
First, I have this list:

```
    liste_path_categories.push(
    { index: null
        , letter: "letter1"
        , type: key
        , picture_url: "url1"
        , id_categ: null
        , response: "Answer here"
    });
```

What I want is to extract from this big list an object in this form:

```
     data["String1"]["String2"]= String3
```

With :

```
    String1=list_path_categories[i].letter
    String2=list_path_categories[i].id_categ
    String3=list_path_categories[i].response
```

example:

```
     data['A']['12'] : "A_answer"
```

To declare the data i make this:

```
       var data = new Object(new Object);
```

How I can set all the values in data?

Comment: Can you explain better your question. I don't understand it well.

Comment: Declaring `new Object` with another inside just creates one object. I would recommend adding the property first and then adding a new object to that. Also you should really use the shorthand method: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate through liste_path_categories and construct your *data* object.

Example:

```
var liste_path_categories = [];
var data = {};

liste_path_categories.push(...);
...
liste_path_categories.push(...);


liste_path_categories.forEach(function(element) {
    data[element.letter] = {};
    data[element.letter][element.id_categ] = element.response;
});
```

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/3ZvNf/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague but do you mean something like this? 
Setting a dynamic property in an object wich belongs to another object?

```
data['A']['12'].answer = "A_answer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strings, you have to use the variables in your property access:

```
var data = {};

if (!data[String1]) {
    data[String1] = {}; // make sure that data[String1] exists and is an object
}

data[String1][String2] = String3;
```

If you want to do this for elements in the array, you have to [iterate over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

---

P.S.: I recommend to use more expressive variable names than `StringX`.

Answer (score 0):

first create the constructor (in OOP terminology):

```
var ctor_object = function(letter,id_categ,response)
{ 
    this.letter = letter;
    this.id_cated = id_categ;
    this.response = response;
}
```

(in genereal you should omit the ctor_ syntax and name it directly after the name of the class of your object)

then use your constructor upon your list of categories:

```
var length = liste_path_categories.length,
    element = null;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  element = liste_path_categories[i];
  my_obj = new ctor_object(element.letter,element.id_categ,element.reponse)
  // Do something with my_obj
}
```